# ggplot and geom_sf not showing graticule and tick marks on world map

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm trying to get a world map using naturalearth data and ggplot2. However, the graticule and axis tick marks and labels are not showing on the x axis in the world map. AFAIK this problem used to be resolved with `coord_sf(expand = FALSE)` (I have old code that uses this), but it no longer seems to be working. I've got a workaround using a different format, but would prefer to be able to do it with sf data.

Any help appreciated!

```
library(ggplot2) # version 3.3.4
library(rnaturalearth) # version 0.1.0
library(sf) # version 1.0-1

map <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = 110, returnclass = "sf")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = map) +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE)
```

Shows gridlines when I change the limits of the coordinates

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = map) +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE,
           xlim = c(0,50),
           ylim = c(0,50))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try deactivating the use of `s2` on `sf` package:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)

map <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = 110, returnclass = "sf")

# Deactivate s2
sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE)


ggplot(map) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE)
```

[image]

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
#> [5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] sf_1.0-1            rnaturalearth_0.1.0 ggplot2_3.3.3      
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.6         pillar_1.6.1       compiler_4.1.0     highr_0.9         
#>  [5] class_7.3-19       tools_4.1.0        digest_0.6.27      lattice_0.20-44   
#>  [9] evaluate_0.14      lifecycle_1.0.0    tibble_3.1.2       gtable_0.3.0      
#> [13] pkgconfig_2.0.3    rlang_0.4.11       reprex_2.0.0       DBI_1.1.1         
#> [17] yaml_2.2.1         xfun_0.23          e1071_1.7-7        withr_2.4.2       
#> [21] styler_1.4.1       stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_1.0.7        knitr_1.33        
#> [25] rgeos_0.5-5        generics_0.1.0     fs_1.5.0           vctrs_0.3.8       
#> [29] classInt_0.4-3     grid_4.1.0         tidyselect_1.1.1   glue_1.4.2        
#> [33] R6_2.5.0           fansi_0.5.0        rmarkdown_2.8      sp_1.4-5          
#> [37] purrr_0.3.4        magrittr_2.0.1     units_0.7-1        backports_1.2.1   
#> [41] scales_1.1.1       ellipsis_0.3.2     htmltools_0.5.1.1  assertthat_0.2.1  
#> [45] colorspace_2.0-1   KernSmooth_2.23-20 utf8_1.2.1         proxy_0.4-25      
#> [49] stringi_1.6.2      munsell_0.5.0      crayon_1.4.1
```

Comment: This answer is based on issue [#4571](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4571). Deactivating `s2` should no longer be needed.