# Map with geom_sf in ggplot2 missing axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, geom

When creating a map in `ggplot2` using `sf`, `geom_sf` I am not seeing any axis labels or graticule.

```r
library("ggplot2")
theme_set(theme_bw())
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

For comparison, [this tutorial](https://r-spatial.org/r/2018/10/25/ggplot2-sf.html) shows the same plot (i.e., based on code) with a graticule and latitude, longitude labels. **Why am I not seeing any?**

`sessionInfo()` below:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] sf_1.0-7      ggplot2_3.3.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8         latex2exp_0.9.3    compiler_3.6.3     pillar_1.7.0       RColorBrewer_1.1-2
 [6] hdf5r_1.3.5        class_7.3-15       tools_3.6.3        digest_0.6.29      bit_4.0.4         
[11] evaluate_0.14      lifecycle_1.0.1    tibble_3.1.6       gtable_0.3.0       pkgconfig_2.0.3   
[16] rlang_1.0.1        DBI_1.1.2          cli_3.2.0          yaml_2.2.2         xfun_0.29         
[21] fastmap_1.1.0      e1071_1.7-9        withr_2.4.3        stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_1.0.8       
[26] knitr_1.37         generics_0.1.2     vctrs_0.3.8        classInt_0.4-3     tidyselect_1.1.2  
[31] bit64_4.0.5        grid_3.6.3         glue_1.6.1         R6_2.5.1           fansi_1.0.2       
[36] rmarkdown_2.11     purrr_0.3.4        magrittr_2.0.2     units_0.8-0        scales_1.1.1      
[41] htmltools_0.5.2    ellipsis_0.3.2     colorspace_2.0-3   KernSmooth_2.23-16 utf8_1.2.2        
[46] proxy_0.4-26       stringi_1.7.6      munsell_0.5.0      crayon_1.5.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disabling spherical geometry seems to be the solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68343004/ggplot-and-geom-sf-not-showing-graticule-and-tick-marks-on-world-map)

```
# Deactivate s2
sf::sf_use_s2(FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
library("ggplot2")
theme_set(theme_bw())
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-79, 79))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am finding, however, that using more restrictive latitude limits still breaks the x-axis labeling; e.g., from your example, change to: `scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-60, 85))`.